# Extracted osm data only shows 3 streets of a city in csv

Tags: csv, openstreetmap

I'm trying to extract the street names of a city from osm data using osmconvert and osmfilter using this command:

```
osmfilter JawaBarat_01.osm --keep="addr:country= and addr:city= Bandung and addr:street=" --ignore-depencencies --drop-relations --drop-ways |osmconvert64 - --csv="@oname @id @lon @lat addr:country addr:city addr:street" >street.csv
```

It yields a csv file, but it contains only 3 roads from the city.

[Extracted csv](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BZJWR.png)

Is it something with my command or is it the osm data? I got the osm by converting it from pbf.

Comment: Hello, I believe --drop-ways might be a bit too much... could you try without it?

Comment: So I tried it without the drops and ignore-dependencies, the command looks like:

`osmfilter JawaBarat_01.osm --keep="addr:country= and addr:city=Bandung and addr:street=" |osmconvert64 - --csv=" @id addr:country addr:city addr:street" >street.csv`

but the result looks like:

https://i.imgur.com/ACI0mbn.png

thanks for the suggestion though.

Comment: What happens if you try it with onyl keep addr:city=Bandung